# CheckForDuplicateEntries': is not a member of 'Microsoft::WRL::Details (C2039)

Tags: visual-c++, sdk, visual-studio-2019, wrl, microsoft-runtime-library

I am programming a DirectX Game and on Debug mode it's working normally,
but on release mode I get 46 Errors of this:
`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error C2039   'CheckForDuplicateEntries': is not a member of 'Microsoft::WRL::Details'    DirectXGame D:\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\winrt\wrl\module.h  1427`

I looked into the module.h code and saw this code:

```
void VerifyEntries() throw()
    {
        // Walk the linker generated list of pointers to CreatorMap for WinRT objects
        for (const Details::CreatorMap** entry = GetMidEntryPointer() + 1; entry < GetLastEntryPointer(); entry++)
        {
            if (*entry == nullptr)
            {
                continue;
            }

            const wchar_t* name = ((*entry)->activationId.getRuntimeName)();
            (name);
            // Make sure that runtime class name is not nullptr and it has no empty string
            __WRL_ASSERT__(name != nullptr && ::wcslen(name) != 0);
        }

        Details::CheckForDuplicateEntries((GetFirstEntryPointer() + 1), GetMidEntryPointer(),
            [](const Details::CreatorMap* entry, const Details::CreatorMap* entry2) -> void {
                __WRL_ASSERT__(entry->activationId.clsid != entry2->activationId.clsid && "Duplicate CLSID!");
            }
        );

        Details::CheckForDuplicateEntries((GetMidEntryPointer() + 1), GetLastEntryPointer(),
            [](const Details::CreatorMap* entry, const Details::CreatorMap* entry2) -> void {
                __WRL_ASSERT__(::wcscmp((entry->activationId.getRuntimeName)(), (entry2->activationId.getRuntimeName)()) != 0 && "Duplicate runtime class name!");
            }
        );
    }
```

But CheckForDuplicateEntries is only allowed on Debug mode:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
template<typename T>
inline void CheckForDuplicateEntries(const CreatorMap** firstEntry, const CreatorMap** lastEntry, T validateEntry) throw()
{
    __WRL_ASSERT__(firstEntry <= lastEntry);
    if (firstEntry == lastEntry)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (const CreatorMap** entry = firstEntry; entry < (lastEntry - 1); entry++)
    {
        if (*entry == nullptr)
        {
            continue;
        }
        // Walk the linker generated list of pointers to CreatorMap
        for (const CreatorMap** entry2 = (entry + 1); entry2 < lastEntry; entry2++)
        {
            if (*entry2 != nullptr)
            {
                (validateEntry)(*entry, *entry2);
            }
        }
    }
}
#endif // _DEBUG
```

Does anyone know how I can get rid of this error?

I tried to remove the #endif define and of course it worked but only in visual studio and no where else.

I'm using vs2019, iso c++ 17, SDK 10.0.17763.0,

Thank you for helping!

**SOLUTION: Updated SDK version from 10.0.17763.0 to 10.0.20348.0**

Answer (score 1):

Windows SDK (17763) is not the 'latest' version.

This specific issue is fixed in the Windows SDK (18362) or later, so I suggest installing a newer version and/or making sure your selection of Windows SDK in the build properties points to the newer one.

At this point, I'd recommend not using any build older than Windows SDK (19041).

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/

Comment: I updated the SDK version. My game works in release mode now, you're right. Thanks!